# Additional tag is coming in XML, which is not declared in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I am new to XML. I was trying with this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE person [
  <!ELEMENT first_name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT last_name  (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT profession (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT name       (first_name, last_name)>
  <!ELEMENT person     (name, profession*)>
]>
<person>
  <name>
    <first_name>Alan</first_name>
    <last_name>Turing</last_name>
  </name>
  <profession>computer scientist</profession>
  <profession>mathematician</profession>
  <job>cryptographer</job>
</person>
```

I am not getting error on browser while opening XML file due to the non existance of tag .
Please help me to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? There is "job" in XML and there is no "job" in definition after "doctype". I have actually no idea what these all are, but I see the error;)

Comment: OK, lets simplify this - if i have typed <profession> tag incorrectly as <professional> then this XML should give error, which is not coming as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I open this xml using IE and there is no error. Then validated it using [w3validator](http://validator.w3.org). Got one error and two warnings as :

warnings :

--No Character encoding declared at document level

--Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed

error :

--element "job" undefined
  cryptographer
✉
You have used the element named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not define an element of that name. This error is often caused by:

incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Frameset" document type to get the "" element),
by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "" or "" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
by using upper-case tags in XHTML (in XHTML attributes and elements must be all lower-case).